# the pacemaker can't start the drbd resource

Tags: high-availability, drbd, pacemaker

here is crm the configure show

```
[root@node1 /]# crm configure show
node node1
node node1.mycluster.org
node node2
node node2.mycluster.org
primitive Apache apache \
        params configfile="/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf" \
        op monitor interval=30s \
        op start timeout=40s interval=0 \
        op stop timeout=60s interval=0 \
        meta target-role=Started
primitive drbd_res ocf:linbit:drbd \
        params drbd_resource=data \
        op monitor interval=29s role=Master \
        op monitor interval=31s role=Slave
primitive failover_ip IPaddr2 \
        params ip=192.168.1.100 cidr_netmask=32 \
        op monitor interval=30s \
        meta target-role=Started
primitive fs_res Filesystem \
        params device="/dev/drbd0" directory="/data" fstype=ext4
ms drbd_master_slave drbd_res \
        meta master-max=1 master-node-max=1 clone-max=2 clone-node-max=1 notify=true target-role=Started
location cli-ban-Apache-on-node2.mycluster.org Apache role=Started -inf: node2.mycluster.org
location cli-ban-drbd_res-on-node1.mycluster.org drbd_res role=Started -inf: node1.mycluster.org
colocation apache_ip_colo inf: Apache failover_ip
colocation fs_drbd_colo inf: fs_res drbd_master_slave:Master
order apache_after_ip Mandatory: failover_ip Apache
order fs_after_drbd Mandatory: drbd_master_slave:promote fs_res:start
property cib-bootstrap-options: \
        dc-version=1.1.10-14.el6_5.3-368c726 \
        cluster-infrastructure="classic openais (with plugin)" \
        expected-quorum-votes=2 \
        stonith-enabled=false \
        no-quorum-policy=ignore
```

before node1: crm resource start drbd_res

```
[root@node2 /]# service drbd status
drbd driver loaded OK; device status:
version: 8.3.16 (api:88/proto:86-97)
GIT-hash: a798fa7e274428a357657fb52f0ecf40192c1985 build by phil@Build64R6, 2013-09-27 16:00:43
m:res   cs         ro                 ds                 p  mounted  fstype
0:data  Connected  Secondary/Primary  UpToDate/UpToDate  C
```

After node1: crm resource start drbd_res

```
 [root@node1 /]# crm resource start drbd_res
    [root@node1 /]# crm status
    Last updated: Thu Nov  6 18:04:43 2014
    Last change: Thu Nov  6 17:51:37 2014 via cibadmin on node1.mycluster.org
    Stack: classic openais (with plugin)
    Current DC: node1.mycluster.org - partition with quorum
    Version: 1.1.10-14.el6_5.3-368c726
    4 Nodes configured, 2 expected votes
    5 Resources configured


    Online: [ node1.mycluster.org node2.mycluster.org ]
    OFFLINE: [ node1 node2 ]

     failover_ip    (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):       Started node1.mycluster.org
     Master/Slave Set: drbd_master_slave [drbd_res]
         Masters: [ node2.mycluster.org ]
         Stopped: [ node1 node1.mycluster.org node2 ]
     fs_res (ocf::heartbeat:Filesystem):    Started node2.mycluster.org
     Apache (ocf::heartbeat:apache):        Started node1.mycluster.org

    Failed actions:
        drbd_res_monitor_29000 on node1.mycluster.org 'ok' (0): call=42, status=complete, last-rc-change='Thu Nov  6 16:02:12 2014', queued=0ms, exec=0ms
        drbd_res_promote_0 on node2.mycluster.org 'unknown error' (1): call=909, status=Timed Out, last-rc-change='Thu Nov  6 15:25:36 2014', queued=20002ms, exec=0ms
```

it brings my drbd on node2 down, and i can't make node2 to secondary back...

```
[root@node2 /]# service drbd status
drbd driver loaded OK; device status:
version: 8.3.16 (api:88/proto:86-97)
GIT-hash: a798fa7e274428a357657fb52f0ecf40192c1985 build by phil@Build64R6, 2013-09-27 16:00:43
m:res   cs          ro               ds                 p       mounted  fstype
0:data  StandAlone  Primary/Unknown  UpToDate/DUnknown  r-----  ext4
```

Any things i go wrong?

Comment: Hi. Have you checked the drbd connection between the two nodes?

Comment: i can sync the node1 to node2 before the command crm resource start drbd_res

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a few things that you can try. Firstly make sure that the nodes can "see" each other.

> node1:~# ping node2 && node2:~# ping node1

There other thing that you shouldn't forget is that Pacemaker must control DRBD. DRBD can't be running when pacemaker starts. If it is you will get all kinds of weird things happening. Other than that you could post your drbd configuration.

Hope this was in someway helpful. Keep us posted, I'm an avid DRBD user myself so I am interested to know the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Having a bit more logs would be helpful, but at f first look it seems odd to me that you have a "target-role=Started" for a master/slave resource. Try removing it.